# Blender unusable due to lag

Tags: modeling

I started using blender yesterday, i have worked on my smartphone desing which looks pretty awful at the moment. the problem is that after opening a file im not able to scale, rotate or move without lag resulting in at least a 5 second freeze or a crash. Im using a 1050 TI with an i7. i have checked that im not accidentally running on integrated graphics. I also tried reinstalling.

Comment: How many vertices are in your model?

Comment: around 2 million

Comment: yes, it says 2 million verts but my model still looks very simple, what is wrong?

Comment: By any chance you applied some subsurf modifiers?

Comment: nope, never heard of it.